# Error con Scanner en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-util-scanner

Este es un programa que deseo realizar:

*Desarrolle un programa  que solicite el nombre de una persona, su edad, su salario. Usted conoce que le realizan un descuento del 15% sobre su salario y le dan un valor de transporte de 80.000 pesos cuando su salario es menor o igual a dos salarios mínimos pesos. Calcule cuánto se gana la persona y muestre su nombre, cuánto es el valor de su descuento y cuánto se gana finalmente*

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que se realizó:

```
package Generales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class actividad2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String nombre = "";
        int edad = 0;
        double salario = 0.0;
        double salario_final = 0.0;
        double descuento = 0.0;
        double porcentaje_descuento = 0.15;
        double transporte = 0.0;
        double salario_minimo = 1961314;
         
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        
    System.out.println("Digite su nombre");
        nombre=entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Digite su salario");
        salario=entrada.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Digite su edad");
        edad=entrada.nextInt();
        
        if(salario<= salario_minimo*2) {
            transporte = 80000;
            
        }
        else {
            transporte = 0;
            
        }
descuento= salario * porcentaje_descuento;
salario_final= salario + transporte - descuento;
System.out.println("el valor del saldo es: "+salario_final);

        
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Como buena práctica, las clases Java se escriben en mayúscula.

Comment: la clase en la imagen es diferente a la del código (actividad1, actividad2). En la imagen no se sabe si había importado la clase Scanner. Por otra parte, no, tú cuéntanos qué error tiene ese código y nosotros te ayudamos a revisar por qué sucede.

Comment: PD. Ni siquiera corriste el código que compartes como texto. El código compila. Voto por cerrar esta pregunta, pues le faltan detalles para poder dar una respuesta. La pregunta en sí no es clara. Y sí, una pregunta debe tener un ejemplo mínimo verificable para recibir una respuesta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola @Dan-code-str en el sitio podemos ayudar, deberías invitar a tu amiga a que se una a la comunidad, no es necesario comentar que el problema es de otra persona, solo debe realizarse de acuerdo a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Entiendo, ¿será eliminada la pregunta?

Comment: Comprendo @Alfabravo , me disculpo por la confusión.

Comment: La imágen fué añadida luego de yo revisar el código, pero en la imágen debes revisar que esté import de Scanner, por otro lado el error que supuse y que encontré lo dejé como respuesta.

Comment: Parece que eclipse tenga un error de compilación, intenta poner import java.util.* u import java.utils.*

Answer (score 2):

Marca como si no tuvieras la definición de la clase `Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Veo que el programa es correcto e incluso tienes la definición de la clase pero el error que se muestra es :

> **Unresolved compilation problems**

Si estas usando Eclipse, este es un problema que en ocasiones sucede cuando se genera un error al compilar, limpia tu proyecto, ve a `Project` > `Clean...`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y vuelve a generar tu proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

*Bueno, realmente lo que puedo observar es lo siguiente:*

*Alhacer uso del **getNext()** en vez del **getNextLine()**, solo se está obteniendo la primer parte del texto que se ingresa, es decir si escribo solo juan el código va a funcionar, pero si ingresas juan perez, solo se va a almacenar en la variable juan y no va  arecoger el resto del nombre.*

*Para que puedas usar el código correctamente, debes reemplazar el **getNext()** por el **getNextLine()**, para que se obtenga todo el texto.*

La información que no se logra obtener al ejecutar un **getNextDouble()** va a tomar lo anterior mas lo que se digite. Supongamos lo siguiente:

cuando me pida el nombre, ingreso Juan Perez. El código continua hasta llegar a pedir el salario. En el punto del nombre solo se tomó Juan. en memoria del scanner queda Perez con el espacio al inicio. Cuando se digita el salario, supongamos que el salario es 50, en el **getNextDouble()** él está intentando retornar un Double, lo que sucede es que está intentando convertir en número caracteres que no son válidos es decir Perez50 con el espcio al inicio. Por eso da el error.

```js
public class actividad2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String nombre = "";
    int edad = 0;
    double salario = 0.0;
    double salario_final = 0.0;
    double descuento = 0.0;
    double porcentaje_descuento = 0.15;
    double transporte = 0.0;
    double salario_minimo = 1961314;

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite su nombre");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite su salario");
    salario = entrada.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite su edad");
    edad = entrada.nextInt();

    if (salario <= salario_minimo * 2) {
      transporte = 80000;

    } else {
      transporte = 0;

    }
    descuento = salario * porcentaje_descuento;
    salario_final = salario + transporte - descuento;
    System.out.println("el valor del saldo es: " + salario_final);



  }

}
```

*Comparto el código con el ajuste realizado, recuerda que las clases se inician con mayuscula.*

*Saludos, espero te sirva*